# Proper use of array in table? Multiple elements of the same field and record

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, table

I have a set of processing priorities that change every day given some user inputs in another program. Each priority has an item and a set of names assigned to it. The names can duplicate across priorities and there usually is multiple names per priority. Is there a better way to organize my priorities table? Am I using the array for the right reasons? Note that field `name_id` in my `priorities` table is an array. The array can be 2500 elements long. I am doing this in PostgreSQL. Happy to supply more details.

Table of `names`:

```
+---------+------+
| name_id | name |
+---------+------+
|       1 | bob  |
|       2 | joe  |
|       3 | ben  |
+---------+------+
```

Table of `items`:

```
+---------+--------+
| item_id |  item  |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | sticks |
|       2 | stones |
|       3 | cars   |
|       4 | buses  |
+---------+--------+
```

Table of `priorities`:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| priority | item_id | name_id |
+----------+---------+---------+
|        1 |       1 | [2,3]   |
|        2 |       3 | [1]     |
|        3 |       4 | [1,2,3] |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not following the [First Normal Form (1NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Your `priorities` table should contain a row per `priority`, `item_id`, and `name_id`:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| priority | item_id | name_id |
+----------+---------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |       2 |
|        1 |       1 |       3 |
|        2 |       3 |       1 |
|        3 |       4 |       1 |
|        3 |       4 |       2 |
|        3 |       4 |       3 |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

This will make it easier to enter or remove a `name_id` from a `priority`/`item_id` combination. All 3 fields should make up the primary key to prevent a double entry.

If you need the `name_id` in an array then you can always create a view for that purpose.

Comment: I thought something was wrong there. Thanks. Glad I posted. Also, on your edit of my question, what do you use to put the tables in one grey block like that?

Comment: For the grey blocks you put in an empty line and then 4 spaces in front of every line.